# Phantomjs not clicking element properly

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, phantomjs

I want to scrape this web page with phantomjs:

http://www1.macys.com/shop/product/john-ashford-shirt-long-sleeve-solid-rugby-polo?ID=875571&CategoryID=20640&LinkType=PDPZ1

and, for each color, get the available sizes. I think this requires `.select()`ing each color, waiting for a bit, and checking which sizes have `class=disabledOption`. Right now I have something that looks like this:

```
get_colors_for_size = (index, color_elem, item_id) ->
    $(color_elem).select()
    setTimeout(->
        size_selector = "#sizeList"+item_id+" > li"
        $(size_selector).each (index, size_elem) ->
            size_name = size_elem.title
            if not $(size_elem).hasClass("disabledOption")
                console.log($(color_elem).title + "  " + size_name)
                #sizes_for_color.push(size_name)
    , 500)

$(color_selector).each (index, color_elem) ->
        color_name = color_elem.title
        console.log(color_name)
        interval = 1000*index      
        console.log(interval)              
        setTimeout(->
           get_colors_for_size(index, color_elem, item_id)
        , interval)
   , item_id, get_colors_for_size
```

However, there's two problems:

1) I don't think the color elements are being selected properly (I've also tried `click()` on them and all their children), since I'm getting the same size options returned for each color
2) This is really ugly and might suffer from race conditions.

Is there another way to execute a blocking workflow, e.g. pause this js execution to wait for other js to execute?

Answer (score 0):

this bug might help? I encountered a similar issue that I was unable to click a link by executing jquery.

https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/355#